# I am forgetting Allah S.W.T what should I do?

Tags: quran, salat

I used to be such a good Muslim I did all good acts prayed and did everything. But now I am turning bad. I disobey and speak rudely to my parents a lot and I used to pray sunnat prayers and nawafil prayers and I used to love praying. But now I hardly pray fard prayer. I want to turn good and seek forgiveness for my sins but I have lost iman and when ever I try to seek forgiveness a wave of anxiety. I need help I don’t know what to do I love Allah but I am forgetting him help me pls.

Comment: I want to go to jannat ul firdous

Comment: Start by ensuring you pray all your fard salah. Read Quran with commentary. Read Islamic books. May Allah increase you in iman, help you reestablish salah and become a better person.

Comment: This site is neither a peer support nor a counselling group. Therefore advise requests are rather off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is required that you keep up with the five daily prayers, and also stay in remembrance of God, for verily with the remembrance of God do hearts find peace.

*Those who have faith and whose hearts find peace in the remembrance of God- truly it is in the remembrance of God that hearts find peace.*

-Quran 13:28

You must also repent to God with a sincere repentance, verily if you repent with a sincere heart then God is indeed Most Forgiving and Most Merciful.

*O you who have believed, repent to God with sincere repentance. Perhaps your Lord will remove from you your misdeeds and admit you into gardens beneath which rivers flow [on] the Day when God will not disgrace the Prophet and those who believed with him. Their light will proceed before them and on their right; they will say, "Our Lord, perfect for us our light and forgive us. Indeed, You are over all things competent."*

-Quran 66:8

You must always stay in remembrance of God, doing upon the will of God, and always staying in humble submission to God.

*Therefore remember Me, I will remember you, and be thankful to Me, and do not be ungrateful to Me.*

-Quran 2:157

Prophet Muhammad said:

*“Whoever says in the morning and in the evening: ‘Subhaan Allaah wa bi hamdihi (Glory and praise be to God)’ one hundred times, no one will come on the Day of Resurrection with anything better than what he has done, except one who said something like what he said, or more than that.”*

-Sahih Muslim 2692

The Prophet Muhammad said:

*Shall I not guide you of something that is better and more beneficial to both of you than whatever you have requested (having a servant)? Whenever you’re about to go to sleep, say Subhanallah 33 times, say Alhamdulillah 33 times, and say Allahu Akbar 34 times. This is better for you than having a servant.*

-Sahih Muslim 2727

The Prophet Muhammad said:

*“Whoever says: ‘Laa ilaaha ill-Allaah wahdahu laa shareeka lah, lahu’l-mulk wa lahu’l-hamd wa huwa ‘ala kulli shay’in qadeer (There is no god but Allah alone with no partner or associate, His is the dominion, to Him be praise and He has power over all things)’ one hundred times in a day, it will be the equivalent of his freeing ten slaves, and one hundred good deeds will be recorded for him, and one hundred bad deeds will be erased for him, and it will be a protection for him against the shaytaan all that day until evening comes, and no one will do anything better than what he has done except one who does more than that.”*

-Sahih al-Bukhari 3293 and Sahih Muslim 2691

The Prophet Muhammad said:

*“Whoever says in the morning and in the evening: ‘Subhaan Allaah wa bi hamdihi (Glory and praise be to Allah)’ one hundred times, no one will come on the Day of Resurrection with anything better than what he has done, except one who said something like what he said, or more than that.”*

-Sahih Muslim 2692

Therefore, I encourage you to do upon all of that, for indeed if you do it and stay in constant remembrance of God, establishing the five daily prayers, repent with a sincere repentance, and be in humble submission to God, then indeed you will be upon the right path, and at the end, everything is in accordance to the will of God.